# Prevent a specific app from accessing the Internet

Tags: macos, network, internet, onenote

I use Microsoft OneNote on my Mac.

How can I can turn off the Internet access to Microsoft OneNote on my Mac?

Answer (score 43):

What you're looking for is called an application firewall. One free/open source program that does this job is called LuLu --  https://objective-see.com/products/lulu.html -- with code on github [here](https://github.com/objective-see/LuLu).

Edit: some example images of the firewall page itself, which pops up when a program makes a connection attempt:

[image: LuLu application firewall]

Rules once made can be configured via an app, which has a UI a bit like this:

[image: Lulu app]

Comment: wonderful solution

Comment: does it work ? is it safe?

Comment: unfortunately you can't build it from sources and then run it without paying 100 bucks to apple

Comment: can its font size changed to smaller?

Answer (score 16):

You can use a 3rd party app called [Little Snitch](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) to block Internet access for individual apps. Little Snitch comes with a limited 30 days free trial and costs € 45 for single user license thereafter.

Another alternative is [Radio Silence](https://radiosilenceapp.com), a network monitor and firewall app for macOS. It lets you control Internet access on an individual app basis. Radio Silence comes with a full 30 days trial and costs US$ 9.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if it cost any money?

Comment: Yes, it's not free, but it is a highly-respected app - https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/order.html

Comment: @Maria Yes, it comes with a limited 30 days trial and costs  € 45 for single user license.

Comment: I'd recommend [Tripmode](https://www.tripmode.ch/) - €7.99 and it's on the App Store.

Comment: Can't the Mac's built-in firewall be used instead?

Comment: @thosphor Mac's build-in firewall can be configured to block incoming connections to apps, not outgoing.

Comment: Little Snitch is too much work.

Comment: @thosphor no one is interested in that, except maybe end user ... but they are at the bottom of the food chain, who cares?

Comment: @Tetsujin I've asked them why they've not published their app on App Store and they were not able to provide adequate answer. Basically they don't want to go through apple app verification process ... so I'll prefer some foss solution to see what happens under the hood

Comment: Is Radio Silence trustable? where do they keep analytics?

Answer (score 7):

You can try Hands Off. It is free. Works almost like Snitch.

https://www.oneperiodic.com/products/handsoff/

Comment: It may have been free in the past, but it's $50 USD now.

Comment: it may have been 50$ in the past, but its dead now

Answer (score 5):

If it is just OneNote you want to block from using Internet you can do that in OneNote app.

You can work offline on OneNote app by turning off the

> automatic sync settings.

Click the Show Navigation icon on the upper-left corner of your OneNote app window and select Settings.

Under Settings, select Options and turn off Sync notebooks automatically using the slider.

It will save your files locally (your hard drive). in

```
~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.onenote.mac/Data/Library/Application Support/Microsoft User Data/OneNote/
```

No need to block internet since already has the option to work offline. (and it is free)

Answer (score 1):

You are certainly looking for a reliable and resilient, yet unobtrusive firewall.
I recommend you to get LuLu, it is free and open source software regularly maintained on Github and does the job perfectly !

https://objective-see.com/products/lulu.html

[image]

Comment: It’s OK to post duplicate answers, but they tend to get voted as second class / less valuable content. Making an edit to an existing post to show a screen shot like this brings lots of value and kudos when done well.